# Mail List Expansion in Trustedbird

Tags: email-client, thunderbird, mail-server

i am trying to develop my own mail client and MTA keeping Trustedbird as a reference.. 
i wanted to know where the Mail list expansion functionality is handled in Trustedbird? at the client or MTA..? couldnt find any documentation related to this..
Thanks in advance..